# WIX 3.10: How to remove environment variables on uninstall?

Tags: wix, environment-variables, uninstallation, wix3

I'm installing some environment variables using WIX.   They don't seem to uninstall.

How can I remove environment variables on feature uninstall ?

Below is the code used to create the env vars:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="create.APACHE.ENV.VARS" Guid="{169CCBDA-23BE-4DC6-8497-BA522DB555C9}" KeyPath="yes">
    <Environment Id="create.ApacheHome"    Name="APACHE_HOME"      Value="[APACHE_INSTALL_DIR]"     Permanent="yes" Part="all" Action="set" System="yes" />
    <Environment Id="create.ApacheConfig"  Name="APACHE_CONFIG"    Value="[INSTALL_DIR]\$(var.APACHE.SVR.CONF.FILE)"     Permanent="yes" Part="all" Action="set" System="yes" />
    <Environment Id="create.ApacheLogs"    Name="APACHE_LOGS"      Value="[APACHE.LOG.DIR]"     Permanent="yes" Part="all" Action="set" System="yes" />
  </Component> 
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: The attribute `@Permanent='yes'` means "... [that the environment variable should not be removed on uninstall.](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/environment.html)"

Comment: Thanks,   This was part of the problem. The other part was domain policy for the user account. No runtime warning issued..

Answer (score 2):

Set `permanent="no"`. Documentation is detailed [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/environment.html).